# How to delete first group '0' in one string

Tags: ruby, string

I want to :

```
000123 -> 123

000123000 -> 123000

0123 -> 123

0102030 -> 102030
```

I want to delete just the top group 0 in one string , who has a good method, thanks!

Comment: Do you want the final result as a number or a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
irb(main):002:0> a = "000123"
=> "000123"
irb(main):003:0> a.sub(/^(0+)/,"")
=> "123"
irb(main):004:0> "000123000".sub(/^(0+)/,"")
=> "123000"
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to get [this](http://rubular.com/r/DtLKikuaUO)

```
str.gsub /^0+/, ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sub(/^0+/,'')
```

Here `^0+` matches one or more `0` at the beginning. `sub` method substitute '' in place of the matched string.

```
def method(str)
  str.sub(/^0+/,'') # use .to_i if you want the result as integer.
end

method('000123') => 123
method('00012300') => 12300
method('0123') => 123
method('0102030') => 102030
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only ever have numeric characters in that string:

```
"000123".to_i.to_s
=> "123"
```

but if there are any likely to be alpha characters, this would give unexpected results.